# probability that exactly 3 tyrosine amino acids will be in a chain of 150 amino acids?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

I hope you can help me with some exercises involving probability theory. In general, I find it super hard to count the situations correct.

Consider a chain of 150 amino acids that codes for an enzyme. (There exist 20 different types of amino acids in total).

a) If you randomly mutate 2 of the 150 amino acids, how many different enzyme variants could you make (By mutating it means changing an amino acid to any of the 20 amino acids. So it is allowed to mutate it to itself).

b) What is the probability that exactly 3 tyrosine amino acids (type of amino acid) will be in the chain of 150 amino acids (non related to question a) ).

c) What is the probability of having at least one tyrosine amino acid in the chain?

---

My attempt:

a) My thought was that there is $\left(\begin{array}{c}150 \\ 2\end{array}\right)$ different ways that I can pick out 2 of the 150 amino acids. And since each amino acid can mutate to 20, there must be $20\left(\begin{array}{c}150 \\ 2\end{array}\right)$ variants in total.

b) There is $(150)^{20}$ different chains I can create (maybe I should divide with 2 if the order doesn't matter). And there must be $\left(\begin{array}{c}150 \\ 3\end{array}\right)$ different ways of having a chain with 3 tyrosine amino acids.
So the probability must be
P=$\left(\begin{array}{c}150 \\ 3\end{array}\right)/150^{20}$

c) It must be equal to 1-probability of having none tyrosine amino acids.
But how do I calculate the probability of having none?

Am I even on the right track? What probability distributions are appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

By your reasoning the answer for (a) in the case of a dipeptide ($2$ amino acids or AAs) would be $20$ and not the correct $400$. Since a mutation can leave the protein unchanged, it is better to count the numbers of proteins that result from mutating $0,1,2$ AAs to *different* instances and add: $1+19\binom{150}1+19^2\binom{150}2$.

Clearly (b) assumes that all AAs are equally likely to appear in a protein, which is flatly false in the real world (e.g. tryptophan is quite rare while leucine is common). Notwithstanding this we can treat the $19$ non-tyrosine (Y) AAs as one "not-Y" type, whereupon the probability is given by the binomial distribution as $\binom{150}3(1/20)^3(19/20)^{147}$.

(c) is like (b) in that you first calculate the probability of no Y – $(19/20)^{150}$ – and take the complement, so the final answer is $1-(19/20)^{150}$.